Can't full disconnect from airplay display
MacOS will not disconnect from a display.
I've clicked "Disconnect" ~20 times with no effect.

Strangely, it also shows I am not connected to any Airplay display.

And then when I try connecting to the display, it fails without any explaination.

This is causing issues as windows keep moving to the phantom display.
How I can I disconnect it?

Can you disconnect if you change the "Use as" setting?

@IconDaemon, no. I set it to mirror thought to make sure that windows don't disappear there.
